# Visual studio MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm currently using Visual studio 2013 professional (with vs 2012 express also installed). I am trying to add the MFC files to my instillation. Is there a way to do this without completely re-installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Control Panel\Programs and Features select Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional.
2. Right click to bring up the context menu.
3. Select Change...
4. In the resulting dialog box, press the Modify button.